# Array of objects convert into object of objects when I use Apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

In our project we use Apollo client to send queries to GraphQL. Strangely it converts the variables into object of objects.

```
let variables = [{myField: "myVal"}];
graphql.mutate("mutate myFunction($data:[MyInputType]){
    myFunction(myArg: $data){...blabla...}
}", variables);
```

When I run the mutation and check request headers, I see that my variables are converted into object of objects.

```
{"0": {"myField": "myVal"}}
```

Does this method force variables to be object by default? Is it possible to send array of objects as parameter using GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing a query, GraphQL expects `variables` to be an object where the key is the variable name and the value is the corresponding variable value. Every variable used within a document (the entire query you send) must be declared next to the operation definition for the document. For example, if you have a variable named `firstName` that was a `String`:

```
mutation SomeOperationName ($firstName: String) {
  # your mutation here
}
```

You can include any number of variables:

```
mutation SomeOperationName ($firstName: String, $lastName: String, points: Int)
```

Variables can also be lists:

```
mutation SomeOperationName ($names: [String], points: Int)
```

In all these cases, however, the value for `variables` you pass to `mutate` still needs to be an object:

```
{
  names: ['Bob', 'Susan'],
  points: 12,
}
```

In your example, you've only defined a single variable, `data`, that you've told GraphQL is a `List` of `MyInputType`. You can't pass in `myField` as a variable because you have not told GraphQL that variable exists. However, if `myField` is a field on `MyInputType`, then your `variables` just needs to look like this:

```
{
  data: [
    {
        myField: 'someValue'
    },
    {
        myField: 'someOtherValue'
    },
  ],
}
```